# Jmeter JSR223 PostProcessor

Tags: jmeter, jsr223, post-processor

2024-01-29 18:27:32,906 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:955) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:573) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.BytecodeInterface8.objectArrayGet(BytecodeInterface8.java:362) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
at Script17.run(Script17.groovy:4) ~[?:?]
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
... 9 more

I'm trying to run a script that works just fine on a coworker's pc,but on mine I have this error in the console of Jmeter, and I cannot understand what seems to be the problem. Can anybody help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it) happens when you try to access an element of an array which doesn't exist.

[image]

So you need to check what object you're passing to the Groovy script, where it comes from and what are the values on your and your "coworker" machines. It might be the case your JMeter installation doesn't have external data file or something like this.

If you're reading the object from a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you can view its value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter).

Comment: I was thinking about that but then neither my coworker can access the element because there's an expired password in between so I was trying to understand why do i see this error and he doesn't. Thank you